# Pokémon Y megastone problem

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm having a hard time with obtaining the post-game mega stones in *Pokémon Y*.  I have beaten The Champ and rival many times & my ring has been upgraded.  I have been looking daily between 8 and 9pm in their proper places.  I think these stones appearing may be a one time deal unless the times are different in version *Y*.

Comment: Which stones have you already found and which ones are you looking for?

Comment: Make sure your 3DS clock is set to the correct time. The stone locations are the same in X and Y but only certain ones will be in each game.

Comment: 'Proper places' Are you sure you got them right? And do you know what the mega stones look like in the overworld?

Comment: Pretty sure it's not a one-time deal. Make sure to set your clock at EXACTLY 8 PM on your 3DS's time, then load up the game and enter a place (the Banette stone is an easy one). You should see purple sparkles. If you're looking for the one behind Abamasnow in the ice cave, it's very hard to see, but it's there.

Answer (score 1):

So I found all the mega stones in my game through this video (Except for the X version exclusives). Easy to follow, just pause the video at some places so you can fly there to get it. Only hard ones to get is Alakazite and scizorite.

Also, If you didn't already know,

Houndoomite, Aggronite, and Heracronite are all found in version Y. Although the pokemon corresponding to these stones are found in version X.

Manectrite, Tyraitarite, and Pinsirite are all found in version X. Although the pokemon corresponding to these stones are found in version Y.

I wouldn't reccommend trading your version exclusive mega stones for the other ones, since you can only acquire them once in the game.